# Multifactor point symbology in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, rendering

I need to symbolize a points currents layer with arrow markers varying by magnitude and direction.

Is there a built-in method to created graduated symbology based on the ranges of two variables or do I need to classify them first to pre-determine the (72!) classes?

[image: Currents]

Comment: Just to be more clear: are we talking about line symbology or point?

Comment: Please provide an example which illustrates your goal, as well as one of your attribute table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the problem I just had this morning - I found a tutorial that helped a lot with that.

How to do it:

- Select the layer & open the Layer Styling
- Select "Rule-based Labeling"
- Here you can add multiple rules (the Plus sign on the bottom) based on different attributes. You can change the marker appearance based on the Expression builder, including scaling and rotating the markers based on the attributes.

The aforementioned tutorial for reference: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/basic_vector_styling.html

Comment: Thanks Hjall I will look into this more in depth!